# There are two ways to initialize members in a C# class via constructor or through member initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor

There are two ways to initialize members in a C# class, via constructor:

```
class MyClass{
  private int Member;
  public MyClass()
  {
    Member = 0;
  }
}
```

or through member initialization:

```
class MyClass
{
  private int Member = 0;
}
```

**My question: Are there problems / benefits of one approach vs. another?**

From what I can see, it's a wash if you only have a default constructor. If you have multiple constructors, member initialization is preferable for those members that are set to the same value by all constructors.

Comment: on a side note: both of those code snippets will produce an FxCop warning because C# already guarantees that `int` fields will be initialized to 0 for you, so doing it yourself is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the execution of your program is concerned, the two examples you gave are identical. Member initialization expressions in your class execute "as-if" they were part of your constructor (IL is identical either way), so it is entirely a matter of style.

The inline initializers are usually more convenient, and are what you are likely to see if you look through existing C# code. Mostly, the initializers in the constructor body are only used when they are necessary, e.g.:

- If you need to compute the initial value using data only known at runtime, e.g. constructor parameters
- If you need (for some reason) to initialize values in a different order than they appear in the code.
- If you need to conditionally initialize certain fields

In those cases, your only option is to have a constructor.

There is one case where the member initialize is explicitly preferred over the constructor body: when the member is `static`. FxCop, for example, will produce a CA1810 or CA2207 if you include a static constructor that initializes static fields. In those cases, there *is* a difference between the inline and constructor body styles, though it is rather technical (see the [CA1810](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182275.aspx) explanation for the gory details.) The recommendation here is to avoid even *having* a constructor: if needed, initialize your static fields with a static member function, called inline:

```
// Don't do this:
public static class Foo
{
  private static int i;
  static Foo()
  {
    i = somecomputedvalue;
  }
}

// Do this:
public static class Foo
{
  private static int i = initializeI();
  private static int initializeI()
  {
    return somecomputedvalue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example, there is no difference.  Initialization in the constructor body is mainly so you can dynamically set the value based on constructor parameters and/or other custom logic.  In this case the compiler will produce the first case I believe even if the original source is the second.

Otherwise it's a case of style and/or repetition.

Personally I prefer to initialize in the constructor body unless I have multiple constructors and having constructors call other constructors isn't appropriate.